# Is there a way to make Bash ignore the '$' from copied commands?

Tags: bash

Online documentation usually lists their commands like

```
$ apt do something
$ make this file
```

It's a little annoying having to copy each line by hand individually since Bash will spit out a 'bash: $: command not found'. A lot of [code blocks](https://japaric.github.io/discovery/03-setup/macos.html) even have a 'copy all to clipboard' button, and I don't get why they'd have that if you can't do anything with it. Is there a way, maybe with aliasing '$' to an empty string, to get around this? Does it make sense to do this?

Comment: In short, no  there isn't.  (AFAIK).  (And '$' is an invalid alias name.  Try it!)

Comment: Complain to the web site that they should remove the prompts when you click on the "copy to clipboard" button. It's really stupid that they don't do this.

Comment: It's usually a hint that (some of) the commands listed might be set up for interactive use... so you might *want* them to copy the lines individually...

Comment: @StephenC, could you make a file `$` that just contained `eval "$@"`, make it executable, and add it to path? It sounds terrible, but also like it might work...

Comment: You could copy the clipboard to a file and then run this: `cut -c2- file | bash`.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, ...it would only work until you had a `cd` or an assignment, or any other command that expects to be able to modify the shell's active state.

Comment: Nope.   That breaks for various edge-cases; e.g. various shell built-in commands.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a small script in `~/bin/` containing something like

```
#!/bin/sh
xclip -o |
    sed 's/^\$ *//' |
    tee /dev/fd/2 |
    xclip -selection clipboard
echo
```

And run it after you copy, but before you paste.

Line-by-line:

- `xclip` writes from/to the clipboard. You may have to install it (with `sudo apt install xclip` on Ubuntu)
- `sed` removes `$` and one or more spaces
- `tee` echoes everything to stderr, so you know what you're about to paste

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way, maybe with aliasing '$' to an empty string, to get around this?

Basically `$` is not a valid name for a Bash alias:

```
$ alias $='echo hello'
bash: alias: `$': invalid alias name

$ alias \$='echo hello'
bash: alias: `$': invalid alias name
```

However it would be possible to create a script (with executable bit set) named `$` and containing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec "$@"
```

and put it in the `PATH`.

I have tested this approach and it partially works (namely, it is OK for simple commands, but obviously not for commands such as `$ variable="value"` nor `$ cd some/folder` because the `$` script is just executed, not sourced).
So, you may want to consider this solution as a workaround.

Comment: Why would you use `eval` at all, vs `"$@"` alone?

Comment: (btw, additional to assignments, this also wouldn't work for any script text that ran `cd`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, thanks! :) I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't work with globs, though, as they are expanded before the script sees them.